# click router c++ standard library

Tags: c++, click, router

Can make click router (http://www.read.cs.ucla.edu/click/) include c++ standard library?

I want to create an element which can generate an txt file, the c++ code just as below:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ofstream out("esp.conf");
    int _spi = 234;
    int _rpl = 300;

    out << _spi << endl;
    out << _rpl << endl;
}
```

Comment: you can use the click-library StringAccum to use similar << syntax and traditional user-level fopen,fwrite to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked this out

You should configure like this: ./configure --enable-userleve --disable-linuxmodule

But, this cannot generate the esp.conf in the directory.